# Identifying strings that contain keywords

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex

How to modify the script highlighting the lines that contain keywords separated by multiple delimiters

I'm not a programmer, but I need to ease my work.
I found a little script that highlights the red lines containing obscene words. Then I manually copy and save the lines just in case.

However, I would like to automate this. I did not find anything similar on the Internet. Therefore, I tried to make a script with my own hands. Here is what I did:

```js
 function extractText(str,delimiter){
   if (str && delimiter){
     var firstIndex = str.indexOf(delimiter)+1;
     var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
     str = str.substring(firstIndex,lastIndex);
   }
   return str;
 }
 
 const keywordsString = ""+
 "stopword|stopword1|stopword2";
 const keywords = keywordsString.split(/#/);
 
 
 const pattern = new RegExp(`(${keywords.join('#')})`, 'g'); 
 
 const phrase = ""+
 "I like cake, pie and<br>cookies keyword keyword<br> stopword<br>";
 
 const result = phrase.replace(pattern, match => `<span style='background-color:red'>${match}</span>`);
 
 setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('prep').innerHTML = result;
 
 if (result.indexOf("span") != -1){
   alert(extractText(result),'&#10');
   document.getElementById('prex').innerHTML = extractText(result,'<br>');
   alert("found");

   }
 }, 100);
```

```html
<pre id="prep" contenteditable="true"></pre>
<pre id="prex" contenteditable="true"></pre>
```

I failed to replace br with \n.
I can select text between words, but how to make the script get all the lines containing stop words.
Then I need to put them in another text block and delete them in the first block.

At first, I wanted the script to sort the lines broken by \n containing swear words by the number of swear words, but it is very difficult, I even failed to select the text.
There you need to use something similar to the Levenshtein distance.

I need to at least find out how to get a set of lines of text that contain stop words separated by \n. Then I can try to solve the rest of the problem itself.

```
   Input
   line of text with words without stopword(two or more)
   line of text with words and <span style='background-color:red'>stopwords</span>
   line of text with words without stopword
   line of text with words and <span style='background-color:red'>stopwords</span>...<span style='background-color:red'>stopwords</span>(two or more)
   line of text with words without stopword

   output1(Filther words)
   line of text with words without stopword(two or more)
   line of text with words without stopword
   line of text with words without stopword

   output2
   line of text with words and <span style='background-color:red'>stopwords</span>
   line of text with words and <span style='background-color:red'>stopwords</span>...<span style='background-color:red'>stopwords</span>(two or more)
```

I want to save all messages containing stop words to another tag. Leave only those that do not contain them.
I need for filher lines that contains stopword

Comment: is that this what are you searching for? https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/YRVMWK?editors=1010

Comment: I do not know how to select text with multiple delimiters and keywords. The example works with only one pair of dividers. And I need to process all that have a tag span. As I understand you just copied my code.

Comment: I fixed your code a little. what do you what to extract from "hello<br>1<br>2<br>yes", having "<br>" as delimiter?

Comment: Script work 1 time for 1 keyword. I need him to be able to process all the lines with spreaders. What do they contain span tag.

Comment: please give an example as input, and the output you want to be more clear to us what do you want.

Comment: Serge,thanks for patienceApparently I do not just explain what I want.

Comment: say, the phrase is "I hate shitty cookies, there are very shitty cookies in this shop", what do you want as output? "I *** ** cookies, there are very *** cookies in this shop"?

Comment: No, I want to save all messages containing stop words to another tag. Leave only those that do not contain them.

Comment: you just copy pasted the same thing, can you give a concrete example, not "other words", a live example, you write "(Text without keyword)" and then you write "keyword"... what is that?

Comment: I need for filher lines that contains stopword.

Comment: please have a look on the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code bellow I take the lines from first blue text area, and separate them in red (bad) and green(good) text areas.

```js
var myLines = $("#s").val().split("\n");

const badWords = ["kaka", "saka", "baka"];
// here we use \bKEYWORD\b in order to keep whole words only
let myExp = new RegExp("(\\b" + badWords.join("\\b)|(\\b") + "\\b)", "g");

var goodLines = [];
var badLines = [];

for (let line of myLines) {
  if (line.match(myExp)) {
    badLines.push(line);
  } else {
    goodLines.push(line);
  }
}

$("#r1").val(goodLines.join("\n"));
$("#r2").val(badLines.join("\n"));
```

```css
#s {background: lightblue;}
#r1 {background: lightgreen;}
#r2 {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="7" id="s" >
line ok
line nok kaka
ok row
  baka this row
sakalento row
lento 'saka' badddd
</textarea>
<textarea rows="5" id="r1"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" id="r2"></textarea>
```

In order to replace all occurrences of "`<br>`" to "`\n`", you can do the following

```
myString.replace(new RegExp(myDelimiter, 'g'), toReplaceChar)
```

console example:

```
>'abc<br>1<br>2<br>3t<br>yyy'.replace(new RegExp("<br>", 'g'), "\n")
"abc
1
2
3t
yyy"
```

Comment: Thank you, I myself began to look for a solution.
It could have been done like this: document.getElementById ("prex"). InnerHTML.split ("\ n");
And then process it as a regular array. And I tried to come up with something very complicated.

Comment: run the code snippet and see the output, is that you wanted?

Comment: observe, the "kakaSomething" would not be taken in consideration, only "kaka" as entire word

Comment: Why this script not support any unicode or symbols such @@?

Comment: what script? what do you mean "not support"